# List the ProductName for all products in the “Classic Cars” product line from the 1960’s

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The difficult thing with this question is the fact that there is no real date and I am supposed to extract the date from a description like this "1960 Ford".

I have tried using a sub-string but I was not successful.
this is the query that I used

```
Select productlines
from  products
where productsline= "Classic cars"
and substring('productname', 1, 4) =>1960 and substring('productname', 1, 4)>=1970
```

Comment: ``AND `productname` REGEXP '.*196[0-9].*$'``.

Comment: @Sik2 . . . You have single quotes around `'productname'`, so that is a string, not a column reference.  I am voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have done correct `query` but just you need to remove `'` sign from sub string function because column name should not define in `string`.

Let me know if you still face difficulty.

Comment: removing the query worked but I cannot be able to specify a range, the code is only working with one year like 1969 could you help me specify a range like =>1960 and=<1960 this is the code   `code`Select productline
from  products
where productline= "Classic cars"
and substring(productname, 1, 4)= 1969

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below SQL Query:

```
Select productlines
from  products
where productsline= "Classic cars"
and CAST(substring('productname', 1, 4) as SIGNED) =>1960 and CAST(substring('productname', 1, 4) as SIGNED)>=1970
```